# Get all dates from dim_table join a fact_table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables in SQL server 2019

A table calendar:

| date_calendar |
| --- |
| 01-01-22 |
| 02-01-22 |
| 03-01-22 |
| 04-01-22 |
| 05-01-22 |
| 06-01-22 |

And a fact table user with some duty:

| user | date_work | duty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 04-01-22 | abc |
| 1 | 04-01-22 | def |
| 2 | 03-01-22 | xyz |
| 2 | 03-01-22 | fgt |
| 2 | 04-01-22 | mop |
| 1 | 05-01-22 | rfg |
| 2 | 06-01-22 | tuy |

and this is the expected result:

| date | user | date_work | duty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-22 | 1 | null | null |
| 01-01-22 | 2 | null | null |
| 02-01-22 | 1 | null | null |
| 02-01-22 | 2 | null | null |
| 03-01-22 | 1 | null | null |
| 03-01-22 | 2 | 03-01-22 | xyz |
| 03-01-22 | 2 | 03-01-22 | fgt |
| 04-01-22 | 1 | 04-01-22 | abc |
| 04-01-22 | 1 | 04-01-22 | def |
| 04-01-22 | 2 | 04-01-22 | mop |
| 05-01-22 | 1 | 05-01-22 | rfg |
| 05-01-22 | 2 | null | null |
| 06-01-22 | 1 | null | null |
| 06-01-22 | 2 | 06-01-22 | tuy |

I tried this:

```
WITH PWR as
(
SELECT 
    user,date_work,duty
FROM Fact_Table
),
calendar as
(
select date_calendar
from Dim_Calendar
)
select 
     date_calendar
    ,pwr.user
    ,pwr.date_work
    ,pwr.duty
from calendar
left join pwr on calendar.date_calendar = pwr.date_work
```

Comment: Do you make the assumption that all users in January were still around in June, and that all users in June were around in January? Are the users stored somewhere else?

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for your CTE, it actively does nothing other than alias the table names.

Then, to guarantee you have every user for every date, regardless of whether they're working, you need to CROSS JOIN the list of dates with the list of users.

Assuming you have a user table, that gives...

```
SELECT
     calendar.date_calendar
    ,user.user
    ,pwr.date_work
    ,pwr.duty
FROM
  dim_calendar   AS calendar
CROSS JOIN
  dim_user       AS user
LEFT JOIN
  fact_table     AS pwr
    ON  pwr.date_work = calendar.date_calendar
    AND pwr.user      = user.user
```

Then, if you need to filter by dates or users, you include the dimension tables in the where clause (not the fact table).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a `Dim_Users` table, you can certainly simulate one:

```
;WITH Dim_Users AS
(
  SELECT [user] 
  FROM dbo.Fact_Table
  GROUP BY [user]
)
SELECT * FROM Dim_Users 
  CROSS JOIN dbo.Dim_Calendar AS dates
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Fact_Table AS f
  ON f.date_work = dates.date_calendar
  AND Dim_Users.[user] = f.[user]
  ORDER BY dates.date_calendar, Dim_Users.[user];
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to start with a master list of each unique date of work and user.

```
select distinct
      c.date_calendar,
      f.user
   from
      calendar c
         cross join fact f
```

Now, that can be the basis of all possible dates and users.  Now, just re-LEFT join back to the user table on the date/user combination

```
select
      AllUniq.date_calendar,
      AllUniq.user,
      f2.date_work,
      f2.duty
   from
      ( select distinct
              c.date_calendar,
              f.user
           from
              calendar c
                 cross join fact f ) AllUniq
         LEFT JOIN fact f2
            on AllUniq.date_calendar = f2.date_work
           AND AllUniq.user = f2.user
```

Comment: @MatBailie, old habit, changed.  I have never used cross-joins in ANYTHING I have ever done.

Comment: Man, you've never lived ;)

Comment: this solution works perfectly, thank you very much I had completely forgotten the cross join... thanks for the help!